# Not able select values which contains space between value name

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP and I have problem to select values which have space between for eg TRANSGENDER FtM, if I use TRANSGENDER-MtF then am able to save it. And same with name input, here is the code:

```
<?php 
include_once 'core/init.php';
$general->logged_out_protect();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" >
    <title>Settings</title>    
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav-bar" style="box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);" >
<?php include 'includes/menu.php'; ?>
</div><!-- NAV BAR DIV closes here -->
    <div id="main-wrap" style=" box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);"> 
    <div id="container">
    <?php
        if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {
            echo '<h3>Your details have been updated!</h3>';            
        } else{

            if(empty($_POST) === false) {       

                if (isset($_POST['first_name']) && !empty ($_POST['first_name'])){
                    if (ctype_alpha($_POST['first_name']) === false) {
                    $errors[] = 'Please enter your First Name with only letters!';
                    }   
                }
                if (isset($_POST['last_name']) && !empty ($_POST['last_name'])){
                    if (ctype_alpha($_POST['last_name']) === false) {
                    $errors[] = 'Please enter your Last Name with only letters!';
                    }   
                }

                if (isset($_POST['gender']) && !empty($_POST['gender'])) {

                    $allowed_gender = array('undisclosed', 'Male', 'Female');

                    if (in_array($_POST['gender'], $allowed_gender) === false) {
                        $errors[] = 'Please choose a Gender from the list'; 
                    }

                } 


                if (isset($_POST['trans']) && empty($_POST['trans'])) {

            $allowed_trans = array(
                                  "--Undisclosed--", 
                                    "Transperson", 
                                    "Transgender", 
                                    "Transsexual  MtF", 
                                    "Transsexual  FtM", 
                                    "Transvestite MtF",
                                    "Transvestite FtM",
                                    "Intergender", 
                                    "Intersexual");

                    if (in_array($_POST['trans'], $allowed_trans) === false) {
                        $errors[] = 'Please choose a Trans from the list if Any';   
                    }

                } 



                if (isset($_FILES['myfile']) && !empty($_FILES['myfile']['name'])) {

                    $name           = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
                    $tmp_name       = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
                    $allowed_ext    = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif' );
                    $a              = explode('.', $name);
                    $file_ext       = strtolower(end($a)); unset($a);
                    $file_size      = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];        
                    $path           = "avatars";

                    if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext) === false) {
                        $errors[] = 'Image file type not allowed';  
                    }

                    if ($file_size > 2097152) {
                        $errors[] = 'File size must be under 2mb';
                    }

                } else {
                    $newpath = $user['image_location'];
                }

                if(empty($errors) === true) {

                    if (isset($_FILES['myfile']) && !empty($_FILES['myfile']['name']) && $_POST['use_default'] != 'on') {

                        $newpath = $general->file_newpath($path, $name);

                        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $newpath);

                    }else if(isset($_POST['use_default']) && $_POST['use_default'] === 'on'){
                        $newpath = 'avatars/default_avatar.png';
                    }

                    $first_name     = htmlentities(trim($_POST['first_name']));
                    $last_name      = htmlentities(trim($_POST['last_name']));  
                    $gender         = htmlentities(trim($_POST['gender']));
                    $bio            = htmlentities(trim($_POST['bio']));
                    $trans          = htmlentities(trim($_POST['trans']));

                    $image_location = htmlentities(trim($newpath));


                    $users->update_user($first_name, $last_name, $gender, $bio, $image_location, $user_id, $trans);
                    header('Location: settings.php?success');
                    exit();

                } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
                    echo '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $errors) . '</p>';  
                }   
            }
            ?>

            <h2>Settings.</h2> <p><b>Note: Information you post here is made viewable to others.</b></p>
            <hr />

            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div id="profile_picture">

                    <h3>Change Profile Picture</h3>
                    <ul>

                        <?php
                        if(!empty ($user['image_location'])) {
                            $image = $user['image_location'];
                            echo "<img src='$image'>";
                        }
                        ?>

                        <li>
                        <input type="file" name="myfile" />
                        </li>
                        <?php if($image != 'avatars/default_avatar.png'){ ?>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="use_default" id="use_default" /> <label for="use_default">Use default picture</label>
                            </li>
                            <?php 
                        }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="personal_info">
                    <h3 >Change Profile Information </h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <h4>First name:</h4>
                            <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['first_name']) ){echo htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['first_name']));} else { echo $user['first_name']; }?>">
                        </li>     
                        <li>
                            <h4>Last name: </h4>
                            <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['last_name']) ){echo htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['last_name']));} else { echo $user['last_name']; }?>">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h4>Gender:</h4>
                            <?php
                                $gender     = $user['gender'];
                                $options    = array("undisclosed", "Male", "Female");
                                echo '<select name="gender">';
                                foreach($options as $option){
                                    if($gender == $option){
                                        $sel = 'selected="selected"';
                                    }else{
                                        $sel='';
                                    }
                                    echo '<option '. $sel .'>' . $option . '</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                            </select>
                        </li><br>
                         <li>
                            <h4>Trans:</h4>
                            <?php
                                $trans  = $user['trans'];
                                $options    = array("--Undisclosed--", 
                                    "Transperson", 
                                    "Transgender", 
                                    "Transsexual  MtF", 
                                    "Transsexual  FtM", 
                                    "Transvestite MtF",
                                    "Transvestite FtM",
                                    "Intergender", 
                                    "Intersexual");
                                echo '<select name="trans">';
                                foreach($options as $option){
                                    if($trans == $option){
                                        $sel = 'selected="selected"';
                                    }else{
                                        $sel="";
                                    }
                                    echo '<option '. $sel .'>' . $option . '</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                            </select>
                        </li><br>







                        <li>
                            <h4>Bio:</h4>
                            <textarea name="bio"><?php if (isset($_POST['bio']) ){echo htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['bio']));} else { echo $user['bio']; }?></textarea>
                        </li>
                    </ul>    
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <hr />
                    <span>Update Changes:</span>
                    <input type="submit" value="Update">

            </form>
   </div><!-- Container DIV closes here -->
    </div><!-- Main Wrap DIV closes here -->
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what exact problem you are having. Can you edit your question to make it clearer? If you can also include what steps you have taken to fix it, that often helps too.

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing the right values? I mean `Transsexual  MtF` ie has **2 spaces** in between

Comment: (Also, it seems that the array of gender names is in your code twice. This may not be the source of the problem, but it's worth not repeating yourself if you can. Search for "DRY programming" for more on this.)

Comment: @Dainis Abols  dear those two spaces was by mistake, the thing is when i go to user account edit page and choose option which have spaces (Transsexual MtF) they doesnt get saved into mysql it gives me error -Please choose a Trans from the list if Any- if i choose option which doesnt have space that goes fine for example (Transgender) ans same in first name field if i enter (Andy) it goes fine if i enter name with space for example (Andy Judge) i get error Please enter your First Name with only letters.

Comment: here is users.php file http://pastebin.com/q188A1Gr

Comment: @halfer no mate there is not gender arrays twice second one is Trans arrays and gender option works fine.

Comment: @andyjudge85: I think we might be talking at cross purposes. The arrays `$allowed_trans` and `$options` are identical, [see here](http://pastie.org/private/xtem116wt6mdwryqdeiqa). If you apply the principle of Don't Repeat Yourself, you will improve the maintainability of your software.

Comment: As for the question itself, it is hard to work out what you mean, especially since it is generating several additional queries in the comments. I would be inclined to recommend you publish a live example that people can try, or screenshot the user interface during an error condition, to make your question clearer.

Comment: here is image with error http://imgur.com/x3dERrY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relation to your screenshot, the problem is that your validation on "First name" is working correctly! I would first suggest that in order to make this change, you should change the form to read "First name(s):" to make it clear that any number of first names are allowed in this field. Ideally you should do this with the field name too.

Your code is thus:

```
if (isset($_POST['first_name']) && !empty ($_POST['first_name'])){
    if (ctype_alpha($_POST['first_name']) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter your First Name with only letters!';
    }
}
```

The function your code uses is [`ctype_alpha`](http://php.net/ctype_alpha), which does not permit spaces. You could change this to:

```
if (isset($_POST['first_name']) && !empty ($_POST['first_name'])){
    // Remove spaces from intermediate variable, to permit them
    $firstNames = str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['first_name']);
    if (ctype_alpha($firstNames) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter your first name(s) with only letters!';
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much mate i was really trying to figure out this ctype_alpha thing , Now it works super fine. you very much, and am just super new to php and programing and waiting for my classes which will start in September :) Best Regards